# Click Button Without ID (VISUAL BASIC)

Tags: vb.net, button

i Have this code

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim allAs As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")

    For Each webpas As HtmlElement In allAs

        If webpas.InnerText = "TEST" Then
            webpas.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When i Click Button3 nothing happend...
Code Button on website (this is not my website )

```
<input class="btn btn_large btn_green" type="submit" value="TEST">
```

i try other code on internet but nothing work... how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `InnerText` property will be empty since there's nothing within the `<input ...></input>` tags, use [**`HtmlElement.GetAttribute()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to check the `value` attribute:

```
If webpas.GetAttribute("value") = "TEST" Then
    webpas.InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to replace your code

```
<input class="btn btn_large btn_green" type="submit" value="TEST">
```

with this

```
<asp:Button id="Button3" runat="server" Text="TEST" class="btn btn_large btn_green"/>
```

Comment: Read the question again: _"(this is not my website )"_ -- And even if it were, who said he would be using ASP.NET?

Comment: Then why he handles button3_click? "Private Sub Button3_Click"

Comment: Because the OP is using [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/). It [includes buttons as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: then how your answer will be helpful when click event never catch in code?

Comment: Because the OP is referring to that he cannot click the button _located on the website that he's **viewing** in the [`WebBrowser` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)_. The WB is what indicates that this is WinForms, by the way. -- Also, if I may ask, how come you didn't reply until almost two years later? :)